# XFCE-like menu in Unity?

Tags: unity, 14.04, launcher, xfce, whisker

I am a new Ubuntu 14.04 user (having moved from Windows XP at the advice of a friend), and I'm loving it!  I like Unity a lot, but one thing that I dearly miss is the Windows Start Menu's folder-like structure to categorize applications in folders (e.g. Games, Internet, Graphics, etc.).  I found and installed XFCE, and I installed the Whisker launcher, and I really like that a lot because they had a similar folder/menu structure of the Windows Start Menu, but Unity works very well on my machine and has obvious advantages over XFCE / Whisker.  I'm wondering, is there some kind of application that I can use in Unity to simulate the Start Menu like functionality of XFCE/Whisker?  For example, is there an application which I can dock in Launcher that LOOKS like the XFCE/Whisher launcher?  The closest thing I could find in Unity was opening Ubuntu Software Center > Installed, and I see them all categorized exactly how I want them, but I can't launch the apps from there.

Here's a mock up of what I'd like to do in Unity:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about this, as I haven't been using unity for a while now but, if I remember correctly, when you open dash you can see the installed applications and you can also filter them by category (similar to XFCE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean something like this: (Sorry I'm on 12.04 but the idea remains)

[image]

- Click on the Applications lens - the second from left at the bottom of the dash.
- Click on Filter results on the top right - highlighted in the screenshot.
- Select the category/categories you want to view apps from.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @Parto.  That's not quite what I'm looking for, though.  I've updated my post with a mock up image of the functionality I seek.  Thanks again!

Comment: What about something like this? It's called the classic menu indicator. http://askubuntu.com/a/46811/163331

Comment: What about something like this? http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/7like-gnomenu-theme-ambiance-meets-windows

Comment: @Parto, ClassicMenu Indicator is exactly what I wanted!  kenn, 7like GNoMenu theme is pretty cool, too.  Thank you both!